# Memory debugging symfony2

Tags: symfony, orm, doctrine

I am using doctrine to insert bulk data in sql. But after inserting 600 to 700 records it gives an error
Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 33554432 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 24 bytes)

I tried increasing the php memory limit but didn't worked .

Here is my code:

function DB_InsertPostTag ($postID, $listSize, $tagList, $tagTypeID,$categoryid)
{

```
 $returnVal = 0;

 $insertList = array(1=>'');

 $insertCount = 0;
         sort($tagList);
         $tagCount = 0;
      for ($i = 0; $i <$listSize; $i++)
      {
           $tagCount++;
           if(isset($tagList[$i+1]))
      {

        if ($tagList[$i] != $tagList[$i+1])
           {
                $insertCount++;
                $tagList[$i];
                $tagCount = 0; //reset the counter

           }

       }
           //else we just ramp the counter
      }
      $batchSize = 1;
     for ($i = 1; $i < $insertCount; $i++)
      {

           $post_tag = new PostTag();
           $post_tag->setPostId($postID);
           $post_tag->setCategoryId($categoryid);
           $post_tag->setTagId($tagList[$i]);
           $post_tag->setTagTypeId($tagTypeID);
           $post_tag->setTagCount($tagCount);
           $em1 = $this->em;
           $em1->persist($post_tag);
            $id = $post_tag->getId();
           if (($i % $batchSize) == 0) {
            $em1->flush();
            $em1->clear(); // Detaches all objects from Doctrine!
        }
        }
        $em1->flush();
        $em1->clear();
      $returnVal = $id;

 return $returnVal;
```

}

Answer (score 0):

If you use DQL, try to make flushes after a certain number of rows, so php can clean those objects from memory.

Comment: I am using flush after every insertion but not working

Comment: The query generation seems fine, if the code before this `for ($i = 1; $i < $insertCount; $i++)` is not generating infinite loop (I could not test it), then try to write the Insert statements manually, without objects. I had to do this when i needed to test a website with millions of users, and doctrine took too much time to generate those entry data with objects.